# Issue binding grouped data to cvs for semantic zoom

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I'm having some trouble getting my semantic zoom bind correctly to my CollectionViewSource. I'm pretty new to MVVM, so I'm not sure i have stuff setup correctly.

View Model

```
    private async void GetData()
    {
        // Simulate pulling data from api
        string response;
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///DesignData/GetLive.json"));
        using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
            response = await sRead.ReadToEndAsync();

        // Deserialize data to class
        LiveStreamModel liveGames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveStreamModel>(response);
        Schedules = liveGames.schedule;

        // Group data by event
        var groupData = liveGames.schedule.GroupBy(a => a.@event);

        // Set cvs source to grouped data
        ScheduleSource = new CollectionViewSource() { IsSourceGrouped = true, Source = groupData };
    }

    private CollectionViewSource scheduleSource;
    public CollectionViewSource ScheduleSource
    {
        get
        {
            return scheduleSource;
        }
        set
        {
            scheduleSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ScheduleSource");
        }
    }
```

View

```
Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="200" Margin="12,6,0,6">
            <!--<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="80" Width="80"/>-->
            <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding homeTeam}" Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding awayTeam}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" 
                           Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInGroupHeaderTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding event}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedOutTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding event}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SemanticZoom x:Name="GetLiveZoom"  >
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <GridView x:Name="GetLiveGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleSource.View}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedInTemplate}" SelectionMode="Single"
                    ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False">
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedInGroupHeaderTemplate}" />
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView> 
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView x:Name="GetLiveList" ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleSource.View.CollectionGroups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoomedOutTemplate}" SelectionMode="None"
                    ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="False"/>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
</Grid>
```

When debugging, my data is getting grouped properly by `@event`, but setting the source of the cvs to the grouped data and binding that to the semantic zoom control results in nothing showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix the following data binding:

**1)** For **ZoomedInGroupHeaderTemplate**, because the Source is grouped data, so if you want to show the group name in ZoomedInView, set data binding for **Key property**:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedInGroupHeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**2)** For **ZoomedOutTemplate**, the Source is ICollectionView.CollectionGroups, ref [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionview.collectiongroups) -> [ICollectionViewGroup interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionviewgroup.aspx)

We need to use [ICollectionViewGroup.Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.icollectionviewgroup.group.aspx) property to get group name in ZoomedOutView:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ZoomedOutTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Group.Key}" Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

**Check my completed sample in [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/SemanticZoomUWPApp1)**

**Screenshot for ZoomedInView:**

[image: ZoomedInView]

**Screenshot for ZoomedOutView:**

[image: ZoomedOutView]